# ESP8266 deep sleep with external wakeup from 2 different GPIO

Tags: arduino, esp8266, switching

I'm trying to create a sensor that checks if the mailbox got new mail and when its emptied (it has 2 diffrent slots)

Is it possible to wake up an ESP8266 and checking which of the microswitches are being triggered?

I know how to reset the esp sending a low pulse on RST but I cannot figure out how to check which switch was triggered when it happened

Comment: to read the switches you have to wire them to an io pin. additionally to wake-up the esp you would need a circuit which sends a pulse on RST if the switch is closed (opened?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [button which wakes up the esp8266 from deep sleep, but can be used as common button](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/404458/button-which-wakes-up-the-esp8266-from-deep-sleep-but-can-be-used-as-common-but)